# Discord.py member.timeout() function doesnt work

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a Discord Bot that is able to Timeout users.
The general idea is that my friends and I can timeout eachother with tickets for about a minute.
But I cant get the discord.Member.timeout() to work.
I looked into the Discord.py doc but I cant find my mistake.
Down below I have put the important code as bold.
The error occures at
print("1")
await member1.timeout(timeout)
print("2")
The program prints "1" and thats it.
The only error message I get is from Discord (This interaction wasnt succesfull)
Please help me.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import random
from discord import app_commands
import datetime

member1 = discord.Member

class SelectMenu3(discord.ui.View):
    options1 = [
        discord.SelectOption(label="Timeouten", value="1", description="Timeout someone"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Enttimeouten", value="2", description="Opposite")
    ]

    @discord.ui.select(placeholder="Options", options=options1)
    async def menu_callback3(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select):
        with open("cogs/eco.json", "r") as f:
            user_eco = json.load(f)
        global member1
        member = interaction.user
        select.disabled = True

        eco_embed = discord.Embed(title="Timeouts", description="", colour=discord.Color.blue())
        eco_embed.add_field(name="Amount Timeout:", value=f"{user_eco[str(member.id)]['Timeout']}")

        **if select.values[0] == "1":
            if user_eco[str(member.id)]['Timeout'] >= 1:
                timeout = datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=1, hours=0, weeks=0)
                print("1")
                await member1.timeout(timeout)
                print("2")

            else:
                await interaction.response.send_message(content="Du hast nicht genug Timeout-Tickets für diese Aktion",
                                                        ephemeral=True)
**
                                                        
        elif select.values[0] == "2":
            if user_eco[str(member.id)]['Timeout'] >= 1:
                pass
            else:
                await interaction.response.send_message(content="Du hast nicht genug Timeout-Tickets für diese Aktion",ephemeral=True)
                                                        

**@app_commands.command(name="timeout", description="")
    async def timeout(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member):
        global member1
        member1 = member
        view = SelectMenu3()
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Choose", view=view,
                                                ephemeral=True)
**
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found the problem, in Discord Roles exist and a User whos Role is lower in the hierarchy cant timeout any users that are higher up.
Therefore I just had to move up my Bots Role to be at the top (still below my own role as a safety measure) and everything is working just fine now.